# Configuration of postgres in Openshift v3

Tags: postgresql, tomcat7, openshift

I have an openshift online v2 app with tomcat. This app connects to a postgres database configured in server.xml.

Now I had to migrate to v3 and my app is giving the following error

```
 Name [jdbc/standard] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

But I don't know how to configure the server.xml in this version.

Can anyone knows how to configure this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [document](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/using_images/xpaas_images/jws.html) has the answer (not tried):

> 2. All WAR files from the deployments source repository directory are copied to /opt/webserver/webapps.
> 3. All files in the configuration source repository directory are copied to /opt/webserver/conf.
>
> If you want to use custom Tomcat configuration files, the file names
>   should be the same as for a normal Tomcat installation. For example,
>   context.xml and server.xml.

Try logging to pod shell via `oc rhc <pod_id>` and explore `/opt/webserver/conf` area.